# JDialog window don't Show

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdialog

I have a JFrame that has an addButton.

When user clicked Button, AddDialog window must show, but I can't see it And Can not Add row

Here's My code:

```
public class AddDialogS extends JDialog{
BookInformation bookinform=new BookInformation();

public AddDialogS(JFrame owner){
    super(owner,"Add New Book!", true);
    JButton OkButton=new JButton("Ok");
   final JTextField nameTF=new JTextField(10);
   final JTextField dateTF=new JTextField(10);
   final JTextField idTF=new JTextField(10);

    OkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bookinform.setBookName(nameTF.getText());
            bookinform.setBookDate(dateTF.getText());
            bookinform.setBookID(idTF.getText());
            AddDialogS.this.dispose();
        }
    });

    JPanel panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(OkButton);
    panel.add(nameTF);
    panel.add(dateTF);
    panel.add(idTF);
}

public BookInformation getBookInfos(){
    return bookinform;
}
}
```

And me main Class:

```
public class MainS extends JFrame{

   final AllBooks allBooks=new AllBooks();
   final JTable Btable=new JTable(allBooks);

   public MainS(){
       JButton AddBookButton=new JButton("Add New Book");
       AddBookButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

           AddDialogS adddialog=new AddDialogS(MainS.this);
           BookInformation B_info=adddialog.getBookInfos();
           if(B_info != null){
               allBooks.AddRow(B_info);
           }
        }
    });

    JPanel Bpanel=new JPanel();
    Bpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(Btable);
    Bpanel.add(sp);
    Bpanel.add(AddBookButton);
    this.add(Bpanel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(300, 60, 550, 550);
    this.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       new MainS();
   }
}
```

It wolud Add a new line to jtable.

Comment: You forgot to add lines, `add(panel);/pack();/setVisible(true);, in  your `AddDislogS``Class's constructor.

Comment: Some points to note, 1) Run the _UI_ on the `EDT` 2) Do not extend `JFrame` or `JDialog`. Instead create a `JFrame` instance in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `dialog.setVisible(true);` in the `actionPerformed()` method of your main class:

```
public class MainS extends JFrame{
...
    public MainS(){
        AddDialogS adddialog=new AddDialogS(MainS.this);
        adddialog.setVisible(true);

        BookInformation B_info=adddialog.getBookInfos();
        ...
```

Comment: But before this, you have to add the `JPanel` to the `JDialog` too and call it's `pack()` method. +1 for the REST :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just creating object of `JDialog` is not going to display it. You must set it visible using `setVisible(true)`.

Also I cant see the size set to your dialog box. You can use `setSize(width, height)` for this.